# Store a series of characters in a char array one at a time

Tags: c, arrays, avr

I am implementing USART communication in AVR.The following function is supposed to receive characters and store them in a char array defined in the main function.

```
    void readString(uint8_t string[], uint8_t maxLength)
{
    uint8_t idx = 0;
    uint8_t data;
    while(idx < (maxLength-1))      // prevent overruns
    {
        data = getByte();   
        transmitByte(data);         // echo the received characters 
        if(data == '\n') break;     // check if enter key is pressed
        else{
            string[idx] = data;
            idx++;
        }   
    }
    string[idx] = 0;                // insert a null character
}
```

Here is the main function:

```
int main(){

initUSART();        // initialize usart 


uint8_t* newString = "Hello";  // test string

uint8_t mString[55];    // store the received characters

readString(mString, 55);    // read array of characters

for(;;){

    transmitString(newString);
    _delay_ms(DELAY);

}

return 0;
```

}

The function below is then supoosed to transmit the received char array back to the USART line

```
  void transmitString(uint8_t* string){
    uint8_t i;
    uint8_t len = sizeof(string);
    for(i=0; i<len; i++){
        transmitByte(string[i]);
    }
}
```

The problem is that the **trannsmitString function** gets nothing to send. I know my **readString function** is not saving the characters into **mString array** declared in the main function. The **getByte function**  works properly. I am able to receive and send a single character but not a string. I can only echo back the received characters one by one. I am having problems inserting these characters into the array for further operations. Using the already declared string, test string,  the function transmits just fine.

Kindly help me out with this problem.

Comment: Is this C or C++?

Comment: `c++` tag seems redundant here as this is pure `C`.

Comment: if you are 100% sure the readString() function is not reading into the array, then the problem likely lies in the getByte() function.  Are you sure you are actually waiting for data to be received?

Comment: @Eljay: Did  you read which platform this is? Your recommendation is complete overkill and a no-go on such platforms. And whether `NUL` is a valid character depends on the definition of the line protocol. In text-based systems it's often not.

Comment: Remove the tag of the unrelated language. C and C++ are different languages. Read [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Please do not edit your question all the time. This makes it a moving target and each hint is useless after a few minutes. That does not attract people to help.

Comment: @Gerhardh Spot on, its changed so many times it may as well be a living evolving creature at this point.

Comment: @Gerhardh Ok. I am not changing anything now

Comment: There are answers posted that point out the problem with the sizeof. Please do not radically edit the post, as that invalidates posted answers. Instead, if you have a follow-up question after fixing the bug, please post a new question. Link to this one if needed. I have made a rollback of the changes so that the posted answers make sense.

Comment: With `sizeof(string)` being 4 or 8 it would still send a few bytes. And it would not work for sending "Hello" either. There must be some other problem as well.

Answer (score 2):

`uint8_t len = sizeof(string);` is not doing what you think it's doing. `len` here will hold the size of a `string` pointer (i.e. it's the same as `sizeof(uint8_t*)`), not the size of the passed array. You need to pass the length as an additional function parameter to get what you want.

Comment: You are correct, but if the data isn't even stored in the array in the first place, he hasn't even got as far as encountering this problem.

Comment: @AndyP I'm not sure that the author is "sure" that it's not stored in the array. The example code tries to send the "test" string anyway.

Comment: The example didn't send the test string when I commented - it's since been edited :(